# Methods to identify a latent sistematic source of noise

Tags: regression, latent-variable, bioinformatics

I am working on modeling the relationship between various biomedical variables (age, sex, diseases ...) and DNA methylation data. DNA methylation data consists of percentages of methylation at many genomic sites. The methods to measure DNA methylation suffer from a type of technical artifact which leads to overestimating the methylation percentage. This stems from inefficiencies in a biochemical reaction that is performed during sample preparation. Unfortunately, there is no direct measurement of this inefficiency, but the effects are very obvious in the data and should apply to every site to some extent (it should have little effect on sites which are near 100% methylation because there is less room to overestimate). Other than that, DNA methylation will be affected by age, sex, diseases, smoking etc... but these relationships will be different for different sites.

What would be the best method to quantify this technical artifact? To me this sounds a bit like factor analysis but some of the factors are known. In general I am very intrigued by the concept of latent variables but I am not experienced with the methods involved. I would appreciate any suggestions regarding what I should look into.